# Password doesn't want to be saved after generating

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I have a problem when I try to save a hashed password. When I used to save it just the way it was it worked but now that I implemented bcrypt it doesn't work anymore. The JSON returned doesn't even contain a password.

Here is my code:

User model:

```
 49 userSchema.methods.registerUser = function(page, body, cb) {
 50   if (page == 1) {
 51     this.username = body.username;
 52     this.email = body.email;
 53     this.generatePassword(body.password, function(err, hash) {
 54       if (err) cb(err);
 55       this.password = hash;
 56     });
 57   } else if (page == 2) {
 58     this.firstName = body.firstName;
 59     this.lastName = body.lastName;
 60     this.gender = body.gender;
 61     this.dateOfBirth = this.createDate(body.day, body.month, body.year);
 62     this.age = this.calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth);
 63   } else {
 64     cb("ERR! Page " + page + " doesnt exist");
 65   }
 66
 67   cb();
 68 };

 84 userSchema.methods.generatePassword = function(password, cb) {
 85   bcrypt.hash(password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
 86     cb(err, hash);
 87   })
 88 };
```

User controller:

```
 11 router.post('/register/:page', function(req, res) {
 12   user.registerUser(req.params.page, req.body, function() {
 13     if (req.params.page == 1) res.redirect('/register/2');
 14     if (req.params.page == 2) res.json(user);
 15   });
 16 });
```

Returned JSON:

```
{"email":"ivan@gmail.com","username":"ivanerlic","age":21,"dateOfBirth":"1994-09-01T05:58:43.204Z","gender":"male","lastName":"Erlic","firstName":"Ivan","_id":"57c670438b0d398f07371386"}
```

As you can see it doesn't return a password. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is becuase of conflicting `this`.

```
userSchema.methods.registerUser = function(page, body, cb) {
 50   if (page == 1) {
 51     this.username = body.username;
 52     this.email = body.email;
        var self = this;
 53     this.generatePassword(body.password, function(err, hash) {
 54       if (err) return cb(err);
 55       self.password = hash;
 56     });
 57   } else if (page == 2) {
 58     this.firstName = body.firstName;
 59     this.lastName = body.lastName;
 60     this.gender = body.gender;
 61     this.dateOfBirth = this.createDate(body.day, body.month, body.year);
 62     this.age = this.calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth);
 63   } else {
 64     cb("ERR! Page " + page + " doesnt exist");
 65   }
 66
 67   cb();
 68 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the callback before the hash is executed.
The correct code should be:

```js
49 userSchema.methods.registerUser = function(page, body, cb) {
 50   if (page == 1) {
 51     this.username = body.username;
 52     this.email = body.email;
 53     this.generatePassword(body.password, function(err, hash) {
 54       if (err) cb(err);
 55       this.password = hash;
         cb();
 56     });
 57   } else if (page == 2) {
 58     this.firstName = body.firstName;
 59     this.lastName = body.lastName;
 60     this.gender = body.gender;
 61     this.dateOfBirth = this.createDate(body.day, body.month, body.year);
 62     this.age = this.calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth);
         cb();
 63   } else {
 64     cb("ERR! Page " + page + " doesnt exist");
 65   }
 68 };
```

If it still doesn't work use the `self` as in the other answer.

Comment: Sure, but you should also use the callback correctly. If such a code involve IO it won't work.

Comment: Yeah I implemented it. Thank you!